# ActiveMQ broker error messages: Async error occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: activemq-classic

I got some messages as below in activemq.log,

```
Async error occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add a producer to a connection that had not been registered: ID:BlackApple-2.local-50258-1366686550079-0:1 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service | ActiveMQ Transport: ssl:///<ip>:50264
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add a producer to a connection that had not been registered: ID:BlackApple-2.local-50258-1366686550079-0:1

Async error occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException | rg.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service | ActiveMQ Transport: ssl:///<ip>:50264
java.lang.NullPointerException

Async error occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot remove a consumer from a connection that had not been registered: ID:BlackApple-2.local-50258-1366686550079-0:1 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service | ActiveMQ Transport: ssl:///<ip>:50264
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot remove a consumer from a connection that had not been registered: ID:BlackApple-2.local-50258-1366686550079-0:1
```

My broker version is 5.6, and I only have one broker(no cluster issue).
What happened and how to fix these? Or is it safe to ignore these error messages?

There are seldom information on the Internet...

Thanks.

EDIT: after getting the full stacktrace with log4j 2 format `%ex{full}` I got more details:

```
org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: peer (vm://broker-amq-2-1-tbk64#3) stopped.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.stop(VMTransport.java:230)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.stop(ResponseCorrelator.java:132)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.doStop(TransportConnection.java:1189)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$4.run(TransportConnection.java:1155)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: You said "can i ignore these messages". Is the system running? Are all messages sended and received?

Comment: Actually, i checked these logs after the broker were running several days later. So, I'm not sure that there are any messages lost or not... If possible, i'd like to find out the root cause and fix it.

Comment: The real cause is hard to find. But the exception is thrown if the connection is closed before the producer is added. May there was a connection failure at this time.

Comment: May you could make an self answer for others with the same problem. Nice to hear the problem is solved.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I didn't get the root cause. I took and accepted your reply, "the exception is thrown if the connection is closed before the producer is added".

Answer (score 0):

Seems like somewhere in the code it's stopping the broker when the broker is already stopped. Haven't found it but seems OK.